# extract values using regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello where is some text patterns like:

```
some text Here +0.25(2)
some text Here 0.25(2.3)
some text Here 0.00(2.3)
some text Here -1.5(1.5)
...
some text Here param_1(param_2)
```

I need to extract two values `param_1` and `param_2`. How to solve it using regexpressions? (needed Javascript)

`param_1` is number contais +, - or nothing perfix.
`param_2` is number

Comment: Do you want every single `param_1` and `param_2` in their own array? So, for example, above code would output: `[0.25, 0.25, 0.00, -1.5]` and `[2, 2.3, 2.3, 1.5]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\((\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?=\))
```

Try this.See demo.Grab the captures.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/25

```
var re = /([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\(\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\))/g;
var str = 'some text Here +0.25(2)\nsome text Here 0.25(2.3)\nsome text Here 0.00(2.3)\nsome text Here -1.5(1.5)\n...\nsome text Here param_1(param_2)';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```

EDIT:

```
(.*?)\s([+-]?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\((\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?=\))
```

use this to capture all three components.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/28

Comment: thanks! Another one, how to get `some text Here` using expressions?

Comment: In the provided demonstration it appears that the parenthesis are captured as well - surely this would be unwanted behaviour?

Comment: @minseong you need to grab tha cpature.edited with final answer as well

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you would like an array of `param_1`s, and then an array of `param_2`s.

### You can accomplish this with two simple regex's:

(to capture `param_1`s):

```
/[+-\d.]+(?=\([\d.]+\)$)/gm
```

[param_1 demo](http://regexr.com/3ab2v)

and [param_2's](http://regexr.com/3ab2s) are even simpler:

```
/[\d.]+(?=\)$)/gm
```

Try the full [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/180Lu2z8/).

```
var param1 = str.match(/[+-\d.]+(?=\([\d.]+\)$)/gm);
var param2 = str.match(/[\d.]+(?=\)$)/gm);
```

`param1` is now an array containing `param_1`s, and `param2` for `param_2`s.